# jQuery Mobile set 'Retina' icons as default

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a jquery mobile based website, and setting the css for retina displays.  Jquery Mobile includes the 36px x 36px icon sizes, but uses the 18px version by default.  I can't find what jQuery Mobile class or data attribute to add to the button to make it use the 36px size.

It looks like the class *ui-icon-alt* uses the proper background image, but the button doesn't render at all when I change the class from *ui-icon* to *ui-icon-alt*.  Here is the button in question I'm working on:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-role="button" class="show-back ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" data-iconpos="notext">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Back</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l"></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: why not just change the css for those classes?

Comment: @sircapsalot ... changing the css will prevent the option of using both the big and small icons on your site ... for example, for some buttons I want the small version, but other more prominent buttons I want the big ones.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd - I don't remember solving this issue.  If I remember correctly, I chalked it up to some error/issue with jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to add anything for your icons to use the *Retina* version.

According to the jQuery Mobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html) In order to use the *retina* icons you should use css media queries (if you take a look at the `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css` file you'll notive that that is how they accomplish it.

> To add a HD icon, create an icon that is 36x36 pixels (exactly double
>   the 18 pixel size), and add second a rule that uses the
>   `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` media query to target a rule only to high resolution displays. Specify the background image for the HD icon
>   file and set the background size to 18x18 pixels which will fit the 36
>   pixel icon into the same 18 pixel space. The media query block can
>   wrap multiple icon rules

And the example css

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .ui-icon-myapp-email {
        background-image: url("app-icon-email-highres.png");
        background-size: 18px 18px;
    }
    ...more HD icon rules go here...
}
```

Comment: I'm specifically looking to use the default jquery mobile icons 36px version.  I've been able to add a custom image and use that 36px version, but my issue is how to make jquery mobile use the 36px version of it's default images.  These images specifically: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/images/icons-36-black.png

Comment: If you are using the default JQM theme css file you shouldn't need to do anything to get the retina icons to be displayed, have a look at line 925 in `jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css`, if you aren't then just copy out that part.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can give is an ID to the anchor like

```
<a id="backBtn" href="#">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Back</span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l"></span>
</span>
```

**NOTE:** You could remove all these span(s) and class(s) if you like and keep it simple And jQuery will take care of the rest of css classes and layout for you. *Example*:

```
<a id="backBtn" href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
```

Then in your my-custom.css you can edit the icon url() for this specific ID, and so long for other buttons you'd like them to use 36px icon instead of 18px. *Example*:

```
#backBtn .ui-icon { 
     width: 36px; 
     height: 36px; 
     background-image: url(images/icons-36-white.png); 
}
```

**Please**, let me know if it answers your question, and if so check it as the right answer.